# Sorting NSFetchedResultsController by NULL NSDates

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nssortdescriptor

I have a tableview that loops through an array of data. The data is a set of contacts that may have a reminder time attached to them. For example:

- Jessica
- John
- Bill
- Katrina (February 9th)
- Brian (February 11th)

Right now, it sorts the tableview via the core-data attribute `reminderDate` in ascending manner. It works semi-correctly. The only catch is I'd like for the items that have a `NULL` `reminderDate` to be thrown to the end of the `NSFetchedResultsController` instead of at the beginning.

Ideally, it'd look like this:

- Katrina (February 9th)
- Brian (February 11th)
- Jessica
- John
- Bill

I can't use a comparative `NSSortDescriptor` as it's not supported by `NSFetchedResultsController`. Also, I'd rather not perform a sorting *after* I get results from the `NSFetchedResultsController` but rather before, when I make the query.

Here is the current code I use:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"User"];
NSSortDescriptor *sortByDate = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"reminderDate" ascending:YES];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortByDate]];
self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                    managedObjectContext:context
                                                                      sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                               cacheName:nil];
```

I believe I should be adding another sortDescriptor, but haven't gotten anything to work properly.

Comment: So sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:comparator: won't work?

Comment: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unsupported NSSortDescriptor (comparator blocks are not supported)'`

Comment: And what about `sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:selector:`?

Comment: Hmmm never tried with selector. Not sure if I even know how to use it. I'll give it a go and report back.

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21643888/using-nssortdescriptor-to-keep-blank-values-down-the-list/21651180#21651180

Comment: Ugh, it's unsatisfying to have to add another column in the User table that is a simple boolean used for sorting. I tried using the selector, but it didn't work. I guess I'll settle for the BOOL sort for now. Thanks.

Comment: Or consider post fetch sorting if it is acceptable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up doing what they mentioned here: [Using NSSortDescriptor to keep blank values down the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21643888/using-nssortdescriptor-to-keep-blank-values-down-the-list/21651180#21651180)

I made a BOOL value that indicates whether or not the user has reminder set. So, I sort by presence of a reminder, and then by date.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortByDate = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"reminderDate" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *sortByHasReminder = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"hasReminder" ascending:NO];
```

It works well. As a database enthusiast, I hate having unnecessary fields, but it's the best I can do with NSSFetchedResultsController.

Comment: This is indeed really frustrating, but I couldn't figure out a different way to solve this either...